# Angular material 2 Sidenav shadow

Tags: angular, angular-material2

What is the best way to remove the shadow from a sidenav?

Here is a link to what it looks like: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9fth.png)

Here is my code:

```html
<md-sidenav-container class="windowFullHeight">

    <md-sidenav #start mode="side" opened="{{globalvariablesservice.SidebarValue()}}">
        <papp-sidebar></papp-sidebar>
    </md-sidenav>

    <div class="noMargin">
        <papp-topbar></papp-topbar>
        <!--<papp-calendar-grid></papp-calendar-grid> Broken-->
        <papp-ads class="vAlignBottom"></papp-ads>
    </div>

</md-sidenav-container>

<div class="container">
    <papp-settings></papp-settings>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it is to just find out appropriate  **`.css`** or **`.scss`** file from **`Angular2-material`**  and selector and change it to desire value.

But I guess, you won't do it. So, other way to do is to target the desire selector and change it accordingly as shown below,

**DEMO** : https://plnkr.co/edit/K3aWIj8d0n4VGNBoGLDV?p=preview

**styles.css**

```
md-sidenav.md-sidenav-opened, md-sidenav.md-sidenav-opening{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```